# Use VBA to screenshot completed userform and attach to email

Tags: excel, vba

The title hopefully says it all...

I have a userform named UserForm1 with a command button named SubmitCommandButton

I want to be able to complete all the fields on the userform, click the SubmitCommandButton and automatically have a screenshot of ONLY the userform saved as an attachment to a pre-defined email. I'm not sure how to go about getting this accomplished in the simplest way possible. I can create the email no problem, but getting the screenshot of the completed userform and getting it saved as an attachment, I cannot seem to figure out.

Your expertise is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: One way or other, I think this will require the WinAPI. See **[this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!topic/microsoft.public.excel.programming/9jH8kkXMPT0)** of the very same question, to get a taste of what that entails.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll start there :)

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904385/using-excel-vba-macro-to-capture-save-screenshot-of-specific-area-in-same-file