# VBA capture part of active window (print screen )

Tags: windows, vba, winapi

I'm trying to capture (printscreen) part of the active window. I'm using this simple and efficient code from [Lutz Gentkow](http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/PrtSc.htm) that works like a charm to capture the whole active window, but I need to capture a defined part of the window only, say a 300 px w x 150 px h.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal _
   bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Private Const VK_SNAPSHOT = &H2C
Private Const VK_MENU = &H12

Sub AltPrintScreen()
     keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0
     keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, 0, 0
     keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
     keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
End Sub
```

Also found [this code](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=1075) from Zack Barresse that does what I want but for the Whole Screen, which make me believe it's possible but capturing from Whole Screen doesn't work for me as I use multiple screens.

Using windows API is out of my scope of knowledge so can anyone point me to the right direction on how to **capture Part of the Active Window, eg defining StartLeft, StartTop, Width, Height ?** by modifying one of this codes?
Thanks

Comment: `by modifying one of this codes` - you can't. You can by throwing this code away and having a completely different code. If you're not happy with that, you can [pretend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43904536/11683) it's just a part of the image.

Comment: If you believe that abusing the clipboard for internal application use is ok, make sure to thoroughly test your uninstaller code.