# VBA - Run excel's built-in Screenshot tool (not ScreenClipping) using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone here have any idea how to row Excel's built-in tool (see screenshot below) and automatically select specified window to capture using VBA Script?

[image]

Comment: Try using the macro recorder, then look at the code and modify as needed to meet your needs.

Comment: ^That does not work. One of many things the recorder ignores/reports incorrectly. I have a workaround though

Comment: @DarrellH, macro recorder does not capture the screenshot tool

Answer (score 0):

What the code below does is essentially press the shortcut keys: Alt+N+SC+C, where Alt=%, N=Insert Ribbon, SC=Screenshot Button, C= Capture Screen Button, you may have to modify depending on language/office version/shortcut setup. I got it working by running the code from a form control button on the worksheet, running from VBA-editor did not work in this case.

```
Sub Screenshot()

SendKeys ("%NSCC"), True

End Sub
```

> Note: You should only use the SendKeys Method if no other option is
>   available, because it can cause problems, if the wrong window is
>   active when the code runs.

_

> Edit: As you have requested to pick one of the windows in the
>   screenshot gallery, i recommend you find the the SendKeys equivalent
>   of TAB and ENTER. Not the best solution i admit, but better than
>   nothing.

_

> Edit2: See this [brilliant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904385/using-excel-vba-macro-to-capture-save-screenshot-of-specific-area-in-same-file):

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and reference. Ill try this one

Comment: It works, I just modify it to %NSC coz I just want to run the screenshot not the screen clipping. One downside though, as you pointed out, the excel file should be a focus window (active window) in the screen in order the for the keyboard shortcut to run as intended. Will try the linked solution