# VBA Excel for capture screenshot with specified region and paste to MS Excel

Tags: excel, vba, screenshot

I have managed with screengrabbing and  copying it into excel.
Unfortunately it looks like the solution presented in the link below;

[Using Excel VBA Macro To Capture + Save Screenshot of Specific Area In Same File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904385/using-excel-vba-macro-to-capture-save-screenshot-of-specific-area-in-same-file)

is not enough for me.

I want to have the image cropped to the specified region of my screen.

My code looks like this:

```
     Sub Screengrab()
     Application.SendKeys "({1068})", True
     DoEvents
     ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B3")

     Dim shp As Shape
     Dim h As Single, w As Single
     With ActiveSheet
     Set shp = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
     End With
     h = -(675 - shp.Height)
     w = -(705 - shp.Width)
     'shp.Height = 2100
     'shp.Width = 2400
     shp.LockAspectRatio = False
     shp.PictureFormat.CropRight = w
     shp.PictureFormat.CropTop = h
    'shp.PictureFormat.offset (-5)
     End Sub
```

[image]

Here is what exactly is happening.
From the code above I am getting the image in the right place, however because it has been cropped I got the leftmost part of the screenshot, which includes the toolbar, which I don't want.
I want to have this cropped region pulled towards right, which would include the workpage instead of side bar.
If I change the code to `shp.PictureFormat.CropLeft = w`i am getting somewhat an opposite part of the desktop, which is good. I could,t complain but it doesn't appear in my printing area, but far away.
I tried also to make the screenshot smaller, although it's too tricky, as the crop doesn't match to the area specified.

Is it some way to offset it properly?

I tried to duplicate the code parameters and do the crops from both sides, but it wasn't work, as the image was gone instantly:

```
     Dim shp As Shape
     Dim h As Single, w As Single ' l As Single, r As Single
     With ActiveSheet
      Set shp = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
     End With
     h = -(675 - shp.Height)
     w = -(705 - shp.Width)
    'l = -(500 - shp.Height)
    'r = -(500 - shp.Width)
    'shp.Height = 2100
    'shp.Width = 2400
    shp.LockAspectRatio = False
    shp.PictureFormat.CropLeft = w
    'shp.PictureFormat.CropLeft = r
    shp.PictureFormat.CropBottom = h
    'shp.PictureFormat.CropTop = l

    End Sub
```

The offset option doesn't work, because is not supported here:
        `'shp.PictureFormat.offset (-5)` as well as:

```
shp.Range("B3").PasteSpecial
```

Is there any way to make the screenshot from the specified region and offset it into my area in the worksheet?

Comment: Which part of your screen are you trying to capture? The window of an application? An area within a specific window? Will the area always be in the same location on the screen, or is it possible that the application window may be moved or resized?

Comment: We can assume, that the location will always be the same. I would like to have the screenshot from screen 2 when possible and it would be best to have it from Visio professional.

Comment: Do you want to paste image into specific cell?

Comment: Yes. I was trying to do the offset but it didn't work. I managed on it so far only on the crop basis. However, It would be brilliant to set some target cells despite the crop region.

Comment: The option:
shp.Range("B3").PasteSpecial didn't work, as VBA doesn't support this property or method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, It looks like I have managed with this problem.

First of all, in order to place our crop in the desired column, we must use the VBA `.Top` and `.Left` location, which basically works as ["moving objects" in VBA Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/moving-objects-with-vba.773982/).

Next, if we want to crop the image from the opposite sides, we need other variables (which I already listed in my previous code, but switched them off). It's worth to know, that if you put the values incorrectly, then your cropped image will be almost gone - the thin bar will appear somewhere in the document. Basically the order of these variables and their values is important. 
If for instance the full screenshot from 2 screens count 3840 x 1080 px, then `.CropLeft` will switch off the leftmost pixels range, i.e Cropleft 1225 will eliminate the 1225 pixels counting from left. In the other hand `.Cropright` must have value bigger than 1225. If for example this `.Cropright` will count 1500, then the pixels between 1500 and 3840 will be removed.
Analogically it works for `.CroopTop` and `.Cropbottom.`

Additionally, we can always use the `.Width` and `.Height` variables in order to suit the cropped screenshot to our worksheet range. The last thing is `.LockAspectRatio = False`, which I would rather not change to `True` because it might result unwanted region cropped from our screen. Instead of it I would advise to manage with the aspect ratio manually, using i.e [this simple tool](https://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/aspect_ratio/).

Finally, I tidied up my code, grouping all the variables in the `With` statements, what looks neater.

```
 Sub CopyScreen()

 Application.SendKeys "({1068})", True
     DoEvents
 ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("B3") ' default target cell, where the topleft corner of our WHOLE screenshot is to be pasted
     Dim shp As Shape
     Dim h As Single, w As Single, l As Single, r As Single
 With ActiveSheet
     Set shp = .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
 End With
 With shp
     h = -(635 - shp.Height)
     w = -(1225 - shp.Width)
     l = -(715 - shp.Height)
     r = -(2860 - shp.Width)
          ' the new size ratio of our WHOLE screenshot pasted (with keeping aspect ratio)
    .Height = 1260 
    .Width = 1680 
    .LockAspectRatio = False
    With .PictureFormat
       .CropRight = r
       .CropLeft = w
       .CropTop = h
       .CropBottom = l
    End With
    With .Line 'optional image borders
      .Weight = 1
      .DashStyle = msoLineSolid
    End With
            ' Moving our cropped region to the target cell
    .Top = Range("B3").Top
    .Left = Range("B3").Left
End With

End Sub
```

[image]