# Application.SendKeys "({1068})", True problem with "Use the Print screen key to open Snipping Tool" accessibility setting in Windows 11

Tags: excel, vba

I have a mature Excel application part of which needs to store evidence of what was being shown at a given time on a UserForm which contains embedded video and other data.

So the UserForm includes a CommandButton called "Screenshot" which takes a screenshot and pastes it into a log workbook. The CommandButton's VBA includes the lines:

```vb
'take a screenshot of the form
    Application.SendKeys "({1068})", True
    DoEvents

'activate the appropriate log worksheet
    wbLog.Sheets("Car " & strCarNumber).Activate

'paste the screenshot into the log worksheet as evidence of the form that was on the screen
   ActiveSheet.Paste
```

This has worked fine since last Summer.

The problem that has arisen is that, where the laptop/PC running the application has the Windows setting "Use the Print screen key to open Snipping Tool" enabled.

If this is the case, the code tries to paste the screenshot before the user has a chance to use the snipping tool. So the code crashes at "ActiveSheet.Paste" as nothing is snipped, so there is nothing to paste.

Manually disabling the "Use the Print screen key to open Snipping Tool" setting in Windows allows the application to work just as it always has.

I do not want the user to use a snipping tool with this application anyway, because the whole point of the screenshot being pasted into a log worksheet is that the worksheet then contains evidence of the whole contents of the form being shown on the screen.

I also don't want a user who likes the snipping tool to have to disable it in settings just to use this application.

So is there any way to:
a) use VBA to bypass/ignore the snipping tool setting
or
b) use VBA to check the status of the snipping tool setting, and if enabled, disable it for this CommandButton, then re-enable it once the screenshot is pasted
or
c) some other solution

Comment: The problem is not the status of the snipping tool, the problem is that you are not taking a screenshot, you are pressing a button. The code to actually take a screenshot will be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55354715/11683 (do not follow the advice in the comments to simply slap a PtrSafe onto everything, that is a [bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801528/11683)).