# Screen capture of one of monitors with taskbar (multiple monitors)

Tags: excel, vba

The solution I'm working on is to allow users make a screenshot (out of excel) and paste it automatically into the worksheet by pressing a shortcut (i.e. Alt+1).
The problem is that I need to have a **taskbar visible** on the screenshot and capture the monitor which is focused (have active window).

I tried to:

- "imitate" PrtSc key press, but it captures all monitors
- "imitate" Alt+PrtSc key press, but it captures active application window wihtout taskbar
- Went through a lot of topics here and not only, and find the [code](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=1075) of Zack Barresse very usefull, but it works only with primary screen.

Any suggestion about the solution or maybe how to modify Zack Barresse' code.

I thought also about identifying monitor resolutions and cursor position, about getting the monitor position and cropping the image however didn't come to final solution and seems that I started to ovethink as there is probably a simpler solution. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of trying differnt things I've got a solution:

```
Option Explicit

Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Type MONITORINFO
    cbSize As Long
    rcMonitor As RECT
    rcWork As RECT
    dwFlags As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function GetMonitorInfo Lib "user32" Alias "GetMonitorInfoA" (ByVal hMonitor As Long, ByRef lpmi As MONITORINFO) As Long
Private Declare Function MonitorFromWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long, ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function BitBlt Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdcDest As Long, ByVal nXDest As Long, ByVal nYDest As Long, ByVal nWidth As Long, ByVal nHeight As Long, ByVal hdcSrc As Long, ByVal nXSrc As Long, ByVal nYSrc As Long, ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteObject Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32" (ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateDC Lib "gdi32" Alias "CreateDCA" (ByVal lpDriverName As String, ByVal lpDeviceName As String, ByVal lpOutput As String, ByVal lpInitData As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32" (ByVal wFormat As Long, ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetObject Lib "gdi32" Alias "GetObjectA" (ByVal hObject As Long, ByVal nCount As Long, lpObject As Any) As Long

Private Const MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY = &H1
Private Const MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST = &H2
Private Const CF_BITMAP = 2

Sub GetActiveWindowMonitorBitmap()
    Dim hwnd As Long
    Dim hMonitor As Long
    Dim mi As MONITORINFO
    Dim hDCScreen As Long
    Dim hDCMem As Long
    Dim hBitmap As Long
    Dim hPrevBitmap As Long
    Dim ret As Long
    Dim hData As Long
    
    ' Get the handle of the active window
    hwnd = GetForegroundWindow()
    
    ' Get the handle of the monitor containing the active window
    hMonitor = MonitorFromWindow(hwnd, MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST)
    
    ' Initialize the structure's size
    mi.cbSize = Len(mi)
    
    ' Get monitor information
    ret = GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, mi)
    
    ' Check if successful
    If ret <> 0 Then
        ' Create a compatible DC for the screen
        hDCScreen = CreateDC("DISPLAY", vbNullString, vbNullString, ByVal 0&)
        
        If hDCScreen <> 0 Then
            ' Create a compatible DC for the bitmap
            hDCMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hDCScreen)
            
            If hDCMem <> 0 Then
                ' Create a compatible bitmap
                hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDCScreen, mi.rcMonitor.Right - mi.rcMonitor.Left, mi.rcMonitor.Bottom - mi.rcMonitor.Top)
                
                If hBitmap <> 0 Then
                    ' Select the bitmap into the memory DC
                    hPrevBitmap = SelectObject(hDCMem, hBitmap)
                    
                    ' Copy the screen to the bitmap
                    ret = BitBlt(hDCMem, 0, 0, mi.rcMonitor.Right - mi.rcMonitor.Left, mi.rcMonitor.Bottom - mi.rcMonitor.Top, hDCScreen, mi.rcMonitor.Left, mi.rcMonitor.Top, &HCC0020)
                    
                    ' Open the clipboard
                    ret = OpenClipboard(0)
                    If ret <> 0 Then
                        ' Empty the clipboard
                        EmptyClipboard
                        
                        ' Set the bitmap data to clipboard
                        ret = SetClipboardData(CF_BITMAP, hBitmap)
                        
                        ' Close the clipboard
                        ret = CloseClipboard
                    End If
                    
                    ' Clean up
                    DeleteObject hBitmap
                Else
                    MsgBox "Failed to create bitmap."
                End If
                
                ' Clean up
                DeleteDC hDCMem
            Else
                MsgBox "Failed to create compatible DC for bitmap."
            End If
            
            ' Clean up
            DeleteDC hDCScreen
        Else
            MsgBox "Failed to create DC for the screen."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Failed to get monitor information."
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" ( _
    ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Declare Function OleCreatePictureIndirect Lib "olepro32.dll" ( _
    ByRef PicDesc As PicBmp, _
    ByRef RefIID As GUID, _
    ByVal fPictureOwnsHandle As Long, _
    ByRef IPic As IPicture) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleDC Lib "gdi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function CreateCompatibleBitmap Lib "gdi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hdc As Long, _
    ByVal nWidth As Long, _
    ByVal nHeight As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function SelectObject Lib "gdi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hdc As Long, _
    ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDeviceCaps Lib "gdi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hdc As Long, _
    ByVal iCapabilitiy As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetSystemPaletteEntries Lib "gdi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hdc As Long, _
    ByVal wStartIndex As Long, _
    ByVal wNumEntries As Long, _
    ByRef lpPaletteEntries As PALETTEENTRY) As Long
Private Declare Function CreatePalette Lib "gdi32.dll" ( _
    ByRef lpLogPalette As LOGPALETTE) As Long
Private Declare Function SelectPalette Lib "gdi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hdc As Long, _
    ByVal hPalette As Long, _
    ByVal bForceBackground As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function RealizePalette Lib "gdi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function BitBlt Lib "gdi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hDestDC As Long, _
    ByVal x As Long, _
    ByVal y As Long, _
    ByVal nWidth As Long, _
    ByVal nHeight As Long, _
    ByVal hSrcDC As Long, _
    ByVal xSrc As Long, _
    ByVal ySrc As Long, _
    ByVal dwRop As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function DeleteDC Lib "gdi32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hdc As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetDC Lib "user32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetWindowRect Lib "user32.dll" ( _
    ByVal hWnd As Long, _
    ByRef lpRect As RECT) As Long
Private Declare Function GetSystemMetrics Lib "user32.dll" ( _
    ByVal nIndex As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32.dll" () As Long

Private Const SM_CXSCREEN = 0&
Private Const SM_CYSCREEN = 1&
Private Const RC_PALETTE As Long = &H100
Private Const SIZEPALETTE As Long = 104
Private Const RASTERCAPS As Long = 38

Private Type RECT
    Left As Long
    Top As Long
    Right As Long
    Bottom As Long
End Type

Private Type PALETTEENTRY
    peRed As Byte
    peGreen As Byte
    peBlue As Byte
    peFlags As Byte
End Type

Private Type LOGPALETTE
    palVersion As Integer
    palNumEntries As Integer
    palPalEntry(255) As PALETTEENTRY
End Type

Private Type GUID
    Data1 As Long
    Data2 As Integer
    Data3 As Integer
    Data4(7) As Byte
End Type

Private Type PicBmp
    Size As Long
    Type As Long
    hBmp As Long
    hPal As Long
    Reserved As Long
End Type

Public Sub prcSave_Picture_Screen() 'ganzer bildschirm
    stdole.SavePicture hDCToPicture(GetDC(0&), 0&, 0&, _
        GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN), GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)), _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Screenshot.bmp" 'anpassen !!!
End Sub

Public Sub prcSave_Picture_Active_Window() 'aktives Fenster
    Dim hWnd As Long
    Dim udtRect As RECT
    Sleep 3000 '3 sekunden pause um ein anderes Fenster zu aktivieren
    hWnd = GetForegroundWindow
    GetWindowRect hWnd, udtRect
    stdole.SavePicture hDCToPicture(GetDC(0&), udtRect.Left, udtRect.Top, _
        udtRect.Right - udtRect.Left, udtRect.Bottom - udtRect.Top), _
        ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Screenshot.bmp" 'anpassen !!!
End Sub

Private Function CreateBitmapPicture(ByVal hBmp As Long, ByVal hPal As Long) As Object
    Dim Pic As PicBmp, IPic As IPicture, IID_IDispatch As GUID
    With IID_IDispatch
        .Data1 = &H20400
        .Data4(0) = &HC0
        .Data4(7) = &H46
    End With
    With Pic
        .Size = Len(Pic)
        .Type = 1
        .hBmp = hBmp
        .hPal = hPal
    End With
    Call OleCreatePictureIndirect(Pic, IID_IDispatch, 1, IPic)
    Set CreateBitmapPicture = IPic
End Function

Private Function hDCToPicture(ByVal hDCSrc As Long, ByVal LeftSrc As Long, _
    ByVal TopSrc As Long, ByVal WidthSrc As Long, ByVal HeightSrc As Long) As Object
    Dim hDCMemory As Long, hBmp As Long, hBmpPrev As Long
    Dim hPal As Long, hPalPrev As Long, RasterCapsScrn As Long, HasPaletteScrn As Long
    Dim PaletteSizeScrn As Long, LogPal As LOGPALETTE
    hDCMemory = CreateCompatibleDC(hDCSrc)
    hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDCSrc, WidthSrc, HeightSrc)
    hBmpPrev = SelectObject(hDCMemory, hBmp)
    RasterCapsScrn = GetDeviceCaps(hDCSrc, RASTERCAPS)
    HasPaletteScrn = RasterCapsScrn And RC_PALETTE
    PaletteSizeScrn = GetDeviceCaps(hDCSrc, SIZEPALETTE)
    If HasPaletteScrn And (PaletteSizeScrn = 256) Then
        LogPal.palVersion = &H300
        LogPal.palNumEntries = 256
        Call GetSystemPaletteEntries(hDCSrc, 0, 256, LogPal.palPalEntry(0))
        hPal = CreatePalette(LogPal)
        hPalPrev = SelectPalette(hDCMemory, hPal, 0)
        Call RealizePalette(hDCMemory)
    End If
    Call BitBlt(hDCMemory, 0, 0, WidthSrc, HeightSrc, hDCSrc, LeftSrc, TopSrc, 13369376)
    hBmp = SelectObject(hDCMemory, hBmpPrev)
    If HasPaletteScrn And (PaletteSizeScrn = 256) Then
        hPal = SelectPalette(hDCMemory, hPalPrev, 0)
    End If
    Call DeleteDC(hDCMemory)
    Set hDCToPicture = CreateBitmapPicture(hBmp, hPal)
End Function
```

"Public Sub prcSave_Picture_Screen()" screenshots the whole window including task bar.
Source: Đức Thanh Nguyễn's answer on this thread [Using Excel VBA Macro To Capture + Save Screenshot of Specific Area In Same File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43904385/using-excel-vba-macro-to-capture-save-screenshot-of-specific-area-in-same-file)

Comment: Hi Kurt, thanks for the answer, it works perfectly with main monitor, but not secondary